# imageview.transform inside UIButton subclass strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11, ios11.2

I had made an `UIButton` subclass and had added an IBInspectable property that rotates the `imageView` inside `UIButton`. In InterfaceBuilder all seems to work perfect but at runtime, it's behaving strangely.

Here's my code

MyButton.m

```
@implementation MyButton



-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setUpView];
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [self setUpView];
    [super layoutSubviews];

}


-(void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder{
    [self setUpView];
}

-(void)setUpView{

    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.angle * M_PI / 180.0);
}

@end
```

It looks like below in Main.storyboard

[image: Series of custom button rotated to look like teeth inside mouth]

What I did here is I had used 32 MyButton to make it look like teeth.

But at runtime, it looks like this

[image: Series of custom button rotated to look like teeth inside the mouth at runtime]

What I tried is :

1. I had commented

   ```
   self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.angle * M_PI / 180.0);
   ```

then button gets proper height width but is not looking good since they require rotation

2. I had changed my code to

   ```
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.angle * M_PI / 180.0);
   ```

and it worked somewhat.

So is there something I am missing or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code seems fine! Are you using auto layout for designing? may be an issue in the auto layout constraints!

Comment: yes am using auto layout and in storyboard everything seems fine no issues with constraints. Shocking stuff is that when I debug view from Xcode then all views are realign properly

Comment: Looks strange! Anyway, you can give it a try by clearing all the constraints and check what is the result

Comment: image set aspectfit and clear constraint and again give them proper constraint.

Comment: Why are you calling [self setUpView]; so many times in different places ?  this is bad practice.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is order. calling layoutSubviews after setUpView, disturbing the UIImageView.

So try just a small fix. change your layout subviews method with this;

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews]; // Supper layoutSubviews should be on top
    [self setUpView]; // and then customization
}
```

so now you should be able to transform your imageView like this;

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.angle * M_PI / 180.0);
```

Thanks;

Comment: Can up please provide a sample project with the issue?

Comment: This solution is not constructive swapping super method call will not alter the incorrect rotation dimensions

Comment: :) Please try it first.